# Xml search in parent node

Tags: xml, xpath, lxml

I have a xml:

```
<data>
    <title>Nice day</title>
    <foo>
        <bar>
        <count>5</count>
        </bar>
    </foo>
</data>
```

At first I search specific node with Xpath

```
e= root.findall('/title/foo/bar/count')
```

Then I check the value of the node with special condition

```
if int(e.text)>0:
```

If node satisfies me, I want to get a value of **title** node.

Now I'm looking for the right xpath syntax for it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fount foo which grandchild count has text and take title text of the same parent

```
//foo[bar/count/text()]/../title/text()
```

Comment: I need to use 'find' from '/title/foo/bar/count' node

Comment: `./../title/text()` ?

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
/data/title[./following-sibling::foo/bar/count[text() > 0]]/text()
```

Checked with `xmllint`:

```
xmllint --xpath '/data/title[./following-sibling::foo/bar/count[text() > 0]]/text()' xmlfile
```

It yields:

```
Nice day
```

Comment: Thank you, but function can't be written in xpath syntax, it's example.